# Detect Specific UI Change in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to detect which UI in a Shiny application was changed? I can do the below to find that a change was made, but is there a way to return that it was "a" or "b" that was changed?

```
uiChange <- reactive({
  input$a
  input$b

  cat("UI CHANGE\n")

  return(TRUE)
})
```